# 108 kb - size of most in-game activation passes, skins, etc... Any idea Why?

Tags: xbox360

I have been playing xbox 360 for a while now and whenever there is a pass, character/weapon skin or even multiplayer access code that needs downloading, the file size is usually 108 kb, no matter the game/application. I've tried googling around and have not come across anything useful. Could someone explain or even speculate why that happens?
I ask out of curiosity :)
Possibly, this question may belong in a different forum - if so, please advise which. :)

Comment: Howdy Atlantis. Inviting speculation isn't what this site is for. We're a Q/A site, not a discussion site. I don't see how knowing the rational behind the activation pass would be helpful to someone trying to develop a game...

Comment: Seems like this has nothing to do with game development?

Answer (score 1):

It's unlock key, that is disguised as downloadable content. 
You would think, that you download new content to your Xbox, but infact, you just unlock content that is already in disk.

Comment: thanks, I realize that - i am just really curious about the fixed 108kb filesize.

Comment: The Xbox probably has a standard way of implementing DLC in games involving a 108kb key file. In all likelihood, it's just a ridiculously large hash, or there's some packaging overhead that's constant for anything downloadable. I can't imagine they're using anything larger than a GUID or SHA512 hash, so the latter is probably the case.

Comment: Hmm... Thanks, @RobertRouhani. That makes things a bit clearer to me.